# Please Help:Grid of JButtons in a JPanel shows one JButton instead of 400 when GridLayout(20,20) is used

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, grid-layout

Thank you for trying to help me.

I want to create a grid of 20*20 squares.It is for my A-Star Algorithm Demo.
For experiment purpose I wrote the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
class Node extends JButton {
Node(){
    super();
    setSize(new Dimension(20,20));
}
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getHeight(),getWidth());
}
}
public class Map 
{
static final int n = 20;
JPanel p;
public JPanel init() {
    p=new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(n, n));
    p.setBackground(Color.black);
    p.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 24));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                p.add(new Node());
        }
    }
    return p;
}
}
public class Display extends JApplet{
   public void init(){
     Map m=new Map();
     add(m.init());

}
}`
```

I got the following output:
*Please load the code & check.I cannot post image since I lack 10 reputation*

However,when I am trying to add the experiment code with my original code for the demo
it is not showing the desired output.My original code is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Node extends JButton implements Comparable<Node>  {
/* Nodes that this is connected to */
private Node north;
private Node east;
private Node south;
private Node west;
private ArrayList<Node> neighbourList;
private boolean visited;
private float g;
private float h;
private Node parent;
private int x;
private int y;
private boolean isObstacle;
private boolean isStart;
private boolean isGoal;

Node(int x, int y) {
    super();
    neighbourList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.visited = false;
    this.g = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    this.isObstacle = false;
    this.isStart = false;
    this.isGoal = false;
}

public void setNorth(Node north) {
    //replace the old Node with the new one in the neighbourList
    if (neighbourList.contains(this.north))
        neighbourList.remove(this.north);
    neighbourList.add(north);
    //set the new Node
    this.north = north;
}

public void setEast(Node east) {
    //replace the old Node with the new one in the neighbourList
    if (neighbourList.contains(this.east))
        neighbourList.remove(this.east);
    neighbourList.add(east);
    //set the new Node
    this.east = east;
}

public void setSouth(Node south) {
    //replace the old Node with the new one in the neighbourList
    if (neighbourList.contains(this.south))
        neighbourList.remove(this.south);
    neighbourList.add(south);
    //set the new Node
    this.south = south;
}

public void setWest(Node west) {
    //replace the old Node with the new one in the neighbourList
    if (neighbourList.contains(this.west))
        neighbourList.remove(this.west);
    neighbourList.add(west);
    //set the new Node
    this.west = west;
}

public ArrayList<Node> getneighbourList() {
    return neighbourList;
}

public boolean isVisited() {
    return visited;
}

public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
    this.visited = visited;
}

public float getG() {
    return g;
}

public void setG(float f) {
    this.g = f;
}

public Node getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Node parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public float getH() {
    return h;
}

public void setH(float h) {
    this.h = h;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public boolean isObstacle() {
    return isObstacle;
}

public void setObstacle(boolean isObstacle) {
    this.isObstacle = isObstacle;
}

public boolean isStart() {
    return isStart;
}

public void setStart(boolean isStart) {
    this.isStart = isStart;
}

public boolean isGoal() {
    return isGoal;
}

public void setGoal(boolean isGoal) {
    this.isGoal = isGoal;
}

public boolean equals(Node node) {
    return (node.x == x) && (node.y == y);
}

public int compareTo(Node otherNode) {
    float thisTotalDistanceFromGoal = h + g;
    float otherTotalDistanceFromGoal = otherNode.getH() + otherNode.getG();
    if (thisTotalDistanceFromGoal < otherTotalDistanceFromGoal) 
        return -1;
    else if (thisTotalDistanceFromGoal > otherTotalDistanceFromGoal) 
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getHeight()-1,getWidth()-1);
}
}

public class Map {
private int mapWidth;
private int mapHeight;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> map;
private int startLocationX = 0;
private int startLocationY = 0;
private int goalLocationX = 0;
private int goalLocationY = 0;
private int[][] obstacleMap;
private JPanel p;
private Logger log = new Logger();
Image buffer;

Map(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, int[][] obstacleMap) {
    this.mapWidth = mapWidth;
    this.mapHeight = mapHeight;
    this.obstacleMap = obstacleMap;
    createMap();
    log.addToLog("\tMap Created");
    registerEdges();
    log.addToLog("\tMap Node edges registered");
}

private void createMap() {
    Node node;
    map = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>>();
    for (int x=0; x<mapWidth; x++) {
        map.add(new ArrayList<Node>());
        for (int y=0; y<mapHeight; y++) {
            node = new Node(x,y);
            if (obstacleMap[x][y] == 1)
                node.setObstacle(true);
            map.get(x).add(node);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Registers the nodes edges (connections to its neighbours).
 */
private void registerEdges() {
    for ( int x = 0; x < mapWidth-1; x++ ) {
        for ( int y = 0; y < mapHeight-1; y++ ) {
            Node node = map.get(x).get(y);
            if (!node.isObstacle()){
                if (!(y==0))
                    node.setNorth(map.get(x).get(y-1));
                if (!(x==mapWidth))
                    node.setEast(map.get(x+1).get(y));
                if (!(y==mapHeight))
                    node.setSouth(map.get(x).get(y+1));
                if (!(x==0))
                    node.setWest(map.get(x-1).get(y));
            }
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> getNodes() {
    return map;
}

public void setObstacle(int x, int y, boolean isObstacle) {
    map.get(x).get(y).setObstacle(isObstacle);
}

public Node getNode(int x, int y) {
    return map.get(x).get(y);
}

public void setStartLocation(Node start) {
    map.get(startLocationX).get(startLocationY).setStart(false);
    map.get(start.getX()).get(start.getY()).setStart(true);
    startLocationX = start.getX();
    startLocationY = start.getY();
}

public void setStartLocation(int x, int y) {
    map.get(startLocationX).get(startLocationY).setStart(false);
    map.get(x).get(y).setStart(true);
    startLocationX = x;
    startLocationY = y;
}

public void setGoalLocation(Node goal) {
    map.get(goalLocationX).get(goalLocationY).setGoal(false);
    map.get(goal.getX()).get(goal.getY()).setGoal(true);
    goalLocationX = goal.getX();
    goalLocationY = goal.getY();
}

public void setGoalLocation(int x, int y) {
    map.get(goalLocationX).get(goalLocationY).setGoal(false);
    map.get(x).get(y).setGoal(true);
    goalLocationX = x;
    goalLocationY = y;
}

public int getStartLocationX() {
    return startLocationX;
}

public int getStartLocationY() {
    return startLocationY;
}

public Node getStartNode() {
    return map.get(startLocationX).get(startLocationY);
}

public int getGoalLocationX() {
    return goalLocationX;
}

public int getGoalLocationY() {
    return goalLocationY;
}

public Node getGoalLocation() {
    return map.get(goalLocationX).get(goalLocationY);
}

public float getDistanceBetween(Node node1, Node node2) {
    //if the nodes are on top or next to each other, return 1
    if (node1.getX() == node2.getX() || node1.getY() == node2.getY()){
        return 1;
    } else { //if they are diagonal to each other return diagonal distance: sqrt(1^2+1^2)
        return (float) 1.4;
    }
}

public int getMapWidth() {
    return mapWidth;
}

public int getMapHeight() {
    return mapHeight;
}

public JPanel init(){ 
    int n=20;
    p=new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(n, n));
    p.setSize(400,400);
    p.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 24));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                p.add(map.get(j).get(i));
        }
    }
    return p;
}

public void clear() {
    startLocationX = 0;
    startLocationY = 0;
    goalLocationX = 0;
    goalLocationY = 0;
    createMap();
    registerEdges();
}

} 

public class Display extends JApplet
{
private static int[][] M =   {{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

public void init()
{ 
    JRootPane rootPane = this.getRootPane();    
    rootPane.putClientProperty("defeatSystemEventQueueCheck", Boolean.TRUE);
    Map m=new Map(20,20,M);
    add(m.init());
}
}
```

This is the output that I got from the above code:
*Please load the code & check.I cannot post image since I lack 10 reputation*

Comment: `extends JApplet`  Why (oh why) an applet?  It is so much easier to develop and debug an application that even if I'm developing an applet, I'll first get it working in an application.   If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I spent a few minutes trying to get the 2nd code to compile, then I stopped. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `Node` class, the methods `getParent`, `getX`, and `getY` are overriding methods in the super class `JButton`.  When the layout manager calls `getX` and `getY` your methods get called which confuses the layout manager.  Rename your three methods to anything else, for example `nodeGetParent`, `nodeGetX`, and `nodeGetY`.

The lesson to learn here is that you must be careful when extending a class that you don't accidentally override the super class' methods.

Comment: Thanks @Barzee next time I would be careful enough to see the 'javadoc'